# Why does the redirected page load on top of the current page in the same browser window?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have figured out a workaround to this problem using Javascript, but would like to know why this is happening, and to figure out a possible solution using PHP.

On my registration page (register.php) I use jQuery's `preventDefault()` on the submit button, but if I call `header("Location: /index.php");` upon successful registration, my index page is loaded on top of my register page. The URL in my browser still says register.php as well.

Redirecting with Javascript solves the problem, but why is this happening with PHP? All other functionality of my registration script works perfectly, including other places where, upon error, I use `header()` to redirect users to my home page (i.e. when users try to navigate directly to .../_registerAccount.php);

jQuery:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-3.3.1.min.js" />

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form").submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var username = $("#register-username").val();
        var email = $("#register-email").val();
        var password = $("#register-password").val();
        var confirmPassword = $("#register-confirm-password").val();
        var submit = $("#register-submit").val();

        $(".form-message").load("../shared/_registerAccount.php", {

            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
            submit: submit

        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
        else
        {
            $errorEmpty = $errorUsername = $errorEmail = $errorPassword = $errorConfirmPassword = false;

            $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPassword);

            mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['register-success'] = 'You have successfully registered! Please verify your email before logging in.';

            $registrationSuccessful = true;

            //My Javascript workaround
            //exit('<script type="text/javascript">location.assign("../index.php")</script><a href="../index.php">Home</a>');

            header('Location: ../index.php');
            exit();
        }
```

Comment: odd issue. can you give me a screenshot when page redirected from php??

Comment: I'm currently not at my home PC, so I can't right now, but essentially the two pages are morphed into each other. It looks like a bad school project.

Comment: After a little more testing today I realized that what's happening is that my jQuery file loads errors into a div specified for form errors, but it's also loading the header command there when my form is successful. I'm not sure if this would be the best solution, but perhaps I should be error checking in the jQuery file as well, and only stopping the form from submitting if there's an error.